# Search a directory for files with fixed name pattern

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, ls

I want to search a directory (let's call it "testDir")  for files which names start with a letter "a", have letter "z" at fourth position and their file extension is .html.

Is there any way to use `grep` for this? How can I search for a character at fixed index?

Comment: I want to print the output to the terminal so (after reading grep manual) I tried: " ls testDir | grep -e 'a' -e 'html' " but I still don't know how to specify the index of a character when looking for a pattern in a filename

Comment: @janos thanks for not giving me a solution right away. Eventually this: " ls test | grep -e "^a..z" | grep html " worked just fine :). Could you explain to me what "^" does in a grep string search?

Comment: Added the explanation of `^` to my answer. If you have further questions on it, post your comment on the answer itself, otherwise I might not notice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use native Bash pattern matching: `a??z*.html`. This pattern means exactly what you're asking for:

- Start with the letter "a"
- Followed by any two characters
- Followed by the letter "z" (4th position)
- Followed by 0 or more characters
- Ending with ".html"

You can get the matching filenames with any shell tool that prints filenames when passed as arguments.
Some examples:

- `ls testDir/a??z*.html` or `echo testDir/a??z*.html`. Note that these will print with the `testDir/` prefix.
- `(cd testDir && echo a??z*.html)` will print just the filenames without the `testDir/` prefix.
- Note that the `ls` command will produce an error when there are no matching files, while the `echo` command will print the pattern (`a??z*.html`).

For more details on pattern matching, see the **Pattern Matching** section in `man bash`.

If you are looking for an alternative that produces no output when there are no matches, `grep` will be easier to use, but `grep` uses different syntax for matching pattern, it uses regular expressions.
The same pattern written in regular expressions is `^a..z.*\.html$`.
This breaks down to:

- `^` means start of line, so `^a` means to start with "a"
- `.` is any character, precisely one
- `.*` is 0 or more of any character
- `\.` is a "."
- `$` means end of line, so `html$` means to end with "html"

Here's one way to apply it to your example:

```
(cd testDir && ls | grep '^a..z.*\.html$')
```

Comment: Thanks for such explicit response! Eventually I came up with a similar grep solution but the one with native pattern matching seems way simpler.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

> ls -d testDir/a??z* |grep -e '.html$'